# Lifecycle hooks in Angular Components, DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, typescript, components

I'm having issues activating the controller lifecycle hooks in my Angular 1.57 / Typescript app. I am using components (not controllers).

The reason i am doing this is because I need to do some DOM manipulation after all of my HTML is loaded. The two methods i've tried so far are below.

The **$postLink** is a NGcontroller lifecycle hook that should fire after all the DOM elements are loaded. This is the first function i have in my component.

The **$viewContentLoaded** essentially does the same thing from what i've seen. I have this inside my **$routerOnActivate** function.

**Method 1**

```
public $postLink(){
    this.log.debug('postLink all done');
}
```

**Method 2**

```
$routerOnActivate(next, prev) {    
    this.$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', (event) => {
        this.log.debug('viewContentLoaded all done');
    });
};
```

With these two methods implemented, the **$postLink all done** log gets triggered before everything else and my **$viewContentLoaded all done** log never gets triggered.

The purpose of this is so i can trigger actions on HTML elements that are on the page. So i need to wait until all the HTML is loaded before i can trigger those actions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a code snippet would help a lot. 
Several things are unclear.

1. are we talking about a Single Page Application, or is just a component?
2. Is this $postLink hook in the main component?
3. Regarding the router please see: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router

> $routerOnActivate / $routeOnReuse : called by the Router at the end of a successful navigation. Only one of $routerOnActivate and $routerOnReuse will be called depending upon the result of a call to $routerCanReuse.

Comment: (1). i am talking about a component within a Single Page App. (2).This is a $postLink hook on the child component (not the main app component)

Comment: Sorry but it is still not 100% clear.

What contents do you need?
> 1. content of the component
> 2. content of the full page << please not this , would be scope widening

For 1. you could also try to use element.ready.

PS.: Components can have controllers by the way - and I suggest that you specify one as a separate file and add all the logic there.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `$postLink()` states that the hook fires before directives with `templateUrl` complete.

> ### Life-cycle hooks
>
> - `$postLink()` - Called after this controller's element and its children have been linked. Similar to the post-link function this hook can be used to set up DOM event handlers and do direct DOM manipulation. Note that child elements that contain **templateUrl directives will not have been compiled** and linked since they are waiting for their template to load asynchronously and their own compilation and linking has been suspended until that occurs.

-- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API -- Life-cycle hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks).

Either avoid directives using `templateURL` or use the `$postLInk()` hook inside those directives to indicate readiness.